# updateTargetedSecurityGroups not working in Intune Graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, intune

I am trying to assign user groups to Managed App Policies in InTune App Protection. I tried below APIs to do it, but none of it works :
POST /managedAppPolicies/ - Added targetedsecuritygroups while creating managed Policy (tried for both iOS and Android)
- Returns 200 but targetedsecuritygroups were not added.

Sample Create Managed App Policy Request:

```
POST /managedAppPolicies/  
Request Body :
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#managedAppPolicies/$entity",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.iosManagedAppProtection",
  "displayName": "Test IOS Policy",
  "description": "test",
  "periodOfflineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT12H",
  "periodOnlineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT30M",
  "allowedInboundDataTransferSources": "allApps",
  "allowedOutboundDataTransferDestinations": "allApps",
  "organizationalCredentialsRequired": false,
  "allowedOutboundClipboardSharingLevel": "allApps",
  "dataBackupBlocked": true,
  "deviceComplianceRequired": true,
  "managedBrowserToOpenLinksRequired": false,
  "saveAsBlocked": false,
  "periodOfflineBeforeWipeIsEnforced": "P90D",
  "pinRequired": true,
  "maximumPinRetries": 5,
  "simplePinBlocked": false,
  "minimumPinLength": 4,
  "pinCharacterSet": "any",
  "allowedDataStorageLocations": [
    "oneDriveForBusiness",
    "sharePoint"
  ],
  "contactSyncBlocked": false,
  "printBlocked": false,
  "fingerprintBlocked": false,
  "targetedSecurityGroupIds": [  "valid directory group id 1",
    "valid directory group id 2" ],
  "appDataEncryptionType": "whenDeviceLocked"
}
```

Response : 200 OK

PATCH /managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId} - Added targetedsecuritygroups while updating managed Policy (tried for both iOS and Android)
- Returns 204 but targetedsecuritygroups are not updated.

Sample request for updating managed app policy:

```
    PATCH /managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId}
Request Body :
    {
      "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#managedAppPolicies/$entity",
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.iosManagedAppProtection",
      "displayName": "Test IOS Policy",
      "description": "test",
      "deployedAppCount": 5,
      "id": "valid id",
      "periodOfflineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT12H",
      "periodOnlineBeforeAccessCheck": "PT30M",
      "allowedInboundDataTransferSources": "allApps",
      "allowedOutboundDataTransferDestinations": "allApps",
      "organizationalCredentialsRequired": false,
      "allowedOutboundClipboardSharingLevel": "allApps",
      "dataBackupBlocked": true,
      "deviceComplianceRequired": true,
      "managedBrowserToOpenLinksRequired": false,
      "saveAsBlocked": false,
      "periodOfflineBeforeWipeIsEnforced": "P90D",
      "pinRequired": true,
      "maximumPinRetries": 5,
      "simplePinBlocked": false,
      "minimumPinLength": 4,
      "pinCharacterSet": "any",
      "allowedDataStorageLocations": [
        "oneDriveForBusiness",
        "sharePoint"
      ],
      "contactSyncBlocked": false,
      "printBlocked": false,
      "fingerprintBlocked": false,
      "targetedSecurityCount" : 1,
      "targetedSecurityGroupIds": ["valid user group id"],
      "appDataEncryptionType": "whenDeviceLocked"
    }
```

Response : 204

POST /managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId}/updateTargetedSecurityGroups
- This API fails with 500
Documentation : 
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_targetedmanagedappprotection_updatetargetedsecuritygroups

Sample Request:

```
POST /managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId}/updateTargetedSecurityGroups
Request Body:
{
  "targetedSecurityGroups": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryObject",
      "id": "valid user group id"
    }
  ]
}

Response : 400
Response Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'updateTargetedSecurityGroups'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "XXX....",
      "date": "2017-02-20T23:35:48"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested in my lab and got the same response (400) as yours. So I think you may have to request a FREE support ticket with Microsoft CSS. Here's guide how to get support:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/troubleshoot/how-to-get-support-for-microsoft-intune

Comment: Hello, have you tried as Alemeshet suggested? It works greatly for me when I use that POST request and get 204 response which means the group update is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with type qualifier like so:

```
POST ~/managedAppPolicies/managedAppPoliciesId}/microsoft.graph.targetedManagedAppProtection/updateTargetedSecurityGroups

{
"targetedSecurityGroups": [
    {"id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/{groupGuidId}"},
    {"id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/{groupGuidId}"}]
}
```